# How to pass some parameter to windows service when run programmatically

Tags: c#, windows-services

i like to know that when we start & stop win service programmatically from another apps then how could i pass some parameter to windows service programmatically....is it possible.

here is my sample code which i use to start service programmatically.

```
private const int RestartTimeout = 10000;

private readonly ServiceController service;

public Control(string serviceName, string computerName)
{
    service = new ServiceController(serviceName, computerName);
}

public Control(string serviceName)
{
    service = new ServiceController(serviceName);
}

public bool StartService()
{
    try
    {
        service.Refresh();

        if (service.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)
        {
            service.Start();
            return true;
        }

        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} --> already started", service.DisplayName));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), @"Error Starting Service");
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ServiceController.Start()` method has an overload that takes an array of strings for parameters which can be implemented further. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9c38b683.aspx

Answer (score -3):

Okay,

i think this ís possible, however, I think it can only be done in a different manner because ServiceController (and Windows Services in general) do not accept parameters.

My guess would be:

1. Stop Service (which starts c:\program.exe "Param A")
2. Delete Service.
3. Add Service (which starts c:\program.exe "Param B")
4. Start Service.

However, I'd recommend getting the parameters (or variables) into the application by using DB connection, resource files - the usual route.

Ofcouse, you could combine both paths, using a config.ini file as paramater and editing this file (once you've stopped the service).

Your application would receive an array of arguments which you can process